# I want to know when to use "has" or "have" with "who"

Tags: grammatical-number

In the sentence, "We want to know who have to pay.", why does "who have" sound wrong?

Comment: Likely because you're only talking about *one* person.

Comment: _Who_ is going to be singular out of context. If you say _the people who have to pay_, then you're clearly talking about a plural pronoun. But consider: if you know every person who has to pay, you know all the people who have to pay. So the plural is rarely needed out of context.